# List cast error when use interface

Tags: java

I have a method with `List` as a parameter.

```
private static void setData(List<IData> list) {

}
```

The `interface IData` is

```
public interface IData {
    int getData();
}
```

And i have a class named `Data` which `implements` the interface of `IData`

```
public class Data implements IData{

    @Override
    public int getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

The question is when I use the parameter of List to call method, it fails to compile.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Data> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            temp.add(new Data());
        }
        setData(temp);

        List<IData> temp2 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            temp2.add(new Data());
        }
        setData(temp2);
    }

    private static void setData(List<IData> list) {

    }
}
```

`setData(temp)` is error. `setData(temp2)` is ok. Both of the lists have same content. I don't understand.

Comment: Use an [upper bound](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html), i.e. `setData(List<? extends IData> list)`

Comment: You could use `private static void setData(List<? extends IData> list) {`, but this might have ramifications to your implementation, personally, I'd just change `List<Data>` to `List<IData>`

Comment: Upper bounds are most useful to people who have obtained the necessary foundation in generics, inheritance, and subtyping. Even with that foundation they are subtle beasts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only put subtypes of parameters in as arguments, because subtypes establish the *is-a* relationship: an instance of a subtype *is-an* instance of the supertypes also. It doesn't matter with your lists what the contents are, only what the list types are, relative to the parameter type expected. Your method `setData(List<IData> list)` requires an argument that *is-a* `List<IData>`, but you tried to pass it a `List<Data>`, which is not a subtype of `List<IData>`. Therefore the compiler could not accept the code.

Generics, inheritance, and subtypes are the topic of the Java Tutorial section entitled "Generics, Inheritance, and Subtypes", which I commend to your attention as a good introduction to the topic. Deeper knowledge will be gained by perusal of Angelika Langer's​ excellent web site pertaining to generics, which I also commend to your attention.